# Why isn't my !important attribute working in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firebug, css-selectors, firebug-lite

I have two CSS files in my web app: reset.css and screen.css.  They appear in that order in the html (reset then screen).

In the reset.css, the following style definition occurs:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  border-bottom-width:0;
  border-color:initial;
  border-left-width:0;
  border-right-width:0;
  border-style:initial;
  border-top-width:0;
  font-family:inherit;
  font-size:100%;
  font-style:inherit;
  font-weight:inherit;
  margin-bottom:0;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
  margin-top:0;
  outline-color:initial;
  outline-style:initial;
  outline-width:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
  padding-top:0;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

You can see that `span` is in this list, and by default has a `font-size` of 100%.

In my screen.css, I have the following:

```
dl.labels-left dt span.req {
  display:inline;
  font-size:14px !important;
}
```

My HTML has the following excerpt:

```
<div>
    <dl class="labels-left">
        <dt class="larger-a-left">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <span class="req">*</span>
        </dt>
...
```

The problem I'm having is that the `font-size: 14px !important;` is being overridden by the CSS in the reset file, *but only in Google Chrome*.  I can't work out why!

Here's a Firebug Lite screenshot showing the `font-size` crossed out:
[Firebug Screenshot http://www.damianbrady.com.au/images/firebug_screenshot.png](http://www.damianbrady.com.au/images/firebug_screenshot.png)

**Why is my reset.css style being considered more important than the specific class definition?**

According to my understanding of [W3C CSS 2.1 Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), this shouldn't happen!

Comment: Is it visually not 14px? Maybe the inspector is crossing it out improperly but visually it's right?

Comment: @meder - you might be onto something there... Can you add this as an answer? :)

Confirmed - the problem is in Firebug Lite (and my vision). Visually, it has been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the inspector is crossing it out improperly but visually it's right?

Comment: Cheers - didn't want to answer it myself when you deserved the points. :) That was exactly the problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing a problem like this and it's not just in the inspector.

Comment: @isomorphismes I solved it with JS onDocumentReady :´(

Answer (score 0):

It is a Firebug Lite bug. Firebug Lite is summing up the specificity value of **each** selector defined in the rule (and not only the matched ones like the CSS specification says), so it is resulting in a overestimated value.

I just filled an issue report for it. Please "star" (subscribe) the issue if you want to receive email updates about our progress with this particular problem:

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3262

Also, next time, for Firebug / Firebug Lite issues, try using our discussion list or our bug tracking. Otherwise we may not be aware of the problem.

Thanks for the detailed report by the way!

Comment: :) Thanks - I'll definitely have a look at the discussion list next time.  Didn't think.