# Browser doesn't rewrite css property

Tags: css, compass-sass

I'm working with compass framework and it resets a lot of default css styles:

```
..., h1, .. {             // line number 18
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Hereinafter i defined my style for `h1`:

```
h1 {                      // line number 77
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  padding: 15px, 5px, !important;
}
```

But chrome browser didn't accept the padding property and left as 0. All another properties are fine.

Why the browser didn't accept the lower css property? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242870/why-isnt-my-important-attribute-working-in-google-chrome

Comment: do you really need `!important` for the padding?

Comment: no, I was just trying to force browser to use my style

Comment: @JMichelB visually it also doesn't work

Comment: Actually, you should remove all commas: `padding: 15px 5px !important;` (and I believe you might not even need `!important` here).

Comment: @bfavaretto- now it works, thanks. I think you should format your note as answer and then I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code modified,

```
h1 {                      // line number 77
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  padding: 15px 5px !important;
}
```

Just remove before important comma.

Please try this..

Comment: sorry dear just put padding: 15px 5px !important;

Answer (score 1):

There should be no comma before `!important`, therefore it's not being obeyed.