# Why is my !important style attribute getting overwritten in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am writing a Chrome extension. And I need all elements to be relative. So I added `position: relative !important;` to `body`'s style to make all of them relative. But in the page I am testing there is some JS that sets some elements' values to `position: fixed`. I thought that the `important` attribute has the most priority in CSS, but somehow the element is still fixed and not relative.

Here is what I am getting in Chrome Inspect:
[image]
(notice the `position: fixed` at the styles' top and `position: relative !important` at the bottom).
And the element is still fixed.

If I uncheck the `position: fixed` rule inside Chrome Inspect, it will become relative, yeah, but that's now what I want to do, I want some JS to make it (actually, all of the elements) relative.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Maybe that my question is related to this: [Why isn't my !important attribute working in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242870/why-isnt-my-important-attribute-working-in-google-chrome), but I'm not sure.

Comment: `important` doesn't negate the cascade...

Comment: `position` is not inheritable...

Comment: Your question title is wrong.  It has nothing to do with Chrome.  And, your !important attribute is not getting overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a style to all elements (which seems wrong / heavy-handed), you'd use some javascript like so:

```
var i;
var bodyElems = document.getElementsByTagName( "body" ) ;
var body = bodyElems[ 0 ] ;
var tags = body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for ( i = 0; i < tags.length; i++ ) {
  tags[i].style.setProperty('position', 'relative', 'important');
}
```

[Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/yjf4kqv7/)

Answer (score 0):

As @dandavis pointed out, the style is being overwritten by more specific CSS. You could always try the "*" selector, or specifying the css position for all tags (body,div,span,etc...).